# How to create a installation Ubuntu flash drive

Tags: system

I have a smal laptop Acer aspire and I wish to install ubuntu from a flash drive how do I proceed?

Comment: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-ubuntu/14011
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-windows/14020
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-macos/14016
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/install-ubuntu-desktop/13618/2

Comment: If Windows is on it and you want to keep Windows, need to make available a partition of at least 20 or 30GBs(more is better).  Read answers and if installing beside Windows, double and triple check you know which partition you want to use and make backups of any data you want to keep.

Comment: Highly recommend - https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Answer (score 1):

1. Burn out your Ubuntu iso image to your flashdrive
2. Disable secure boot in BIOS if enabled
3. Insert it into your laptop's USB port
4. Turn on your laptop and boot from your flashdrive
5. Select Try Ubuntu without installing
6. Check if everything is detected and working: wi-fi, ethernet, sound, video, hdd, ssd, etc.
7. If everything is working, than you could [install Ubuntu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VM4l__C08YE) on your laptop

Comment: Looks complete and simple but may need to edit BIOS to boot USB.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the official workflow from Ubuntu's own tutorials.

Download Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download
or for a supported 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours .

The ISO file you use to create a LiveUSB should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 .

Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 .

Once you make a LiveUSB, install from it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0